# framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist using Swift and Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode

It is not possible to start the project. I receive this:

> Bundle at path
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B7EE295-6BF3-41B6-ACA8-D4771EC65AB3/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2zLdYH/extracted/Payload/example.app/Frameworks/LocationPickerViewController.framework
>   did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

Im using cocapods. Any ideas?

'Clean solution' did not help to me.
No files exist inside /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B7EE295-6BF3-41B6-ACA8-D4771EC65AB3/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/

Comment: Having the same issue... Could you solve it?

Comment: I've added this lib as separated project. Not cocoapod

Answer (score 5):

For me cleaning the build folder worked. In Xcode, hold alt Product -> Clean Build Folder..

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I had to delet derived data nd swithecd form iPad2 to iPad Air

Answer (score -3):

1. First Quit Simulator
2. Quit Xcode
3. Open Xcode
4. Alt + Prodect-> clean Build Folder 
   it will work InshaAllah